# How do I get Google Drive access for a desktop app?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to write a Python program that uses Google Drive to do some custom backup and sync work from my Linux desktop.
I started using the PyDrive2 library, and followed its recommendations on how to sign up for Drive API access. When I run my program, it accesses Drive as I'd expect it to, but my authorization expires after a few hours, which is not going to work for a program that runs in cron. I thought this might be because my app is not verified, so I looked into verification, but it's asking for things like a my application's home page. Mine isn't a web-based application, so I don't have one.

Is there a good way to access Google Drive APIs from a non-web application?

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 1):

if your access is expireing after only a few hours it sounds like you are not requesting offline access and storing the refresh token for later use.

If you followed [Quickstart pyton](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) You may have noticed this section.   The users credetinals that being the refresh otken and the access token are stored in token.json for future use by your application.

```
# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
```

> I thought this might be because my app is not verified, so I looked into verification, but it's asking for things like a my application's home page.

Your application only really needs to be verified if you are going to have other uses using it.  If your only using it yourself then you really only need to remove it from testing phase and put it into production then your refresh tokens will last longer then seven days.

You could try to use a service account but i don't know of anyone who has gotten service account authorization to work with curl.

Comment: I created a new GCP project, following the instructions in the Quickstart, published it, then ran the Quickstart. The token it downloaded has an ```"expiry"``` field eight hours in the future, which is the problem I was having with my token that PyDrive2 acquires. I ran it a second time, and it does not update the token expiration.

Comment: once you have a refresh token it won't always give you a new one every time